# Applescript to move pdf files onto droplet from folder

Tags: applescript, automator

is it possible to write an Applescript to use in an Automator Folder Action which would push pdf files dropped into this folder to a preflight droplet?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1):

If the droplet is an Automator application, you can just use `open -a`:

[image]

If the droplet is an AppleScript application with an `open` handler, `open -a` doesn't work, but you can use Finder's `open` command:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have set out the workflow as you have shown but when I drop a pdf file into the folder it doesn't move it to the preflight droplet??

Comment: Thanks again, the droplet is an Acrobat Preflight droplet. I am a complete noob with Applescript, should I just be able to cut & paste your script and it work? It doesn't move the pdf to the Preflight droplet.

Comment: @user2652638, will you send me a copy of your workflow?  Remember to compress it (archive it) as a .zip file before you attach it to your email.  http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=zip  my email address: kaydell@yahoo.com